# Nginx downloading specific PHP file instead of executing

Tags: nginx, php, docker, rewrite

I moved a small bundle of scripts from Apache to Nginx. This is a directory full of files, where specific extensions (php, txt, js, html) need to be shown through one script, other files need to be downloaded, and directories need to be browseable. To note, gallery.php is currently not being used. All of this was functional with the htaccess below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !prettify.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !upload.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !gallery.php
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(php|txt|js|html)) prettify.php?f=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]

RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3
php_flag engine off
```

After trying a bunch of stuff, I landed on this nginx config, which allows me to see the main directory through index.php:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 8M;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name paste.<host>;

    error_log /vmdata/services/web/logs/paste.error.log;
    access_log /vmdata/services/web/logs/paste.access.log;

    root /vmdata/services/web/vhosts/paste;
    index index.php;

    location /index.php {
        fastcgi_pass php_php73-fpm:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /prettify.php {
        fastcgi_pass php_php73-fpm:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /upload.php {
        fastcgi_pass php_php73-fpm:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /gallery.php {
        fastcgi_pass php_php73-fpm:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    
    location ~* ^(.*\.(php|txt|js|html))$ {
        try_files prettify.php?f=$1;
    }

    location ~* ^(.*)/$ {
        try_files index.php?dir=$1;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?dir=$1;
    }
}
```

Files download fine, but the files matched by the location block for specific extensions start a download, containing the source of prettify.php. Directories don't go to index.php, but simply cause a 404.

What am I doing wrong here? From what I understand, the 4 specific PHP file location blocks should be executed first (as they're the longest), but somehow this isn't working.

I could find lots of similar questions, but sadly none that really helped me

Any guidance would be much appreciated, if there's specific reading I can do to actually understand where it's going wrong that would be even better.

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`.

Comment: Oh, I guess that could be the culprit:
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:39

Comment: `location ~* ^(.*\.(php|txt|js|html))$` will match all of your `.php` URIs and stop PHP from working (even after you fix the error).

Comment: @RichardSmith but nginx matches non-regex rules first, according to the docs, which is why I added those 4 specific location blocks

Comment: It's the other way around unless you use either the `=` or `^~` operator with those other four `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Aha! Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: `php_flag engine off` turning php off?